# How to plot multiple decision curve analysis survival models (cox proportional hazard regression) in a single dca plot on R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, cox-regression

Can someone please help me with the following:

I am trying to create a decision curve analysis plot from survival data. I would like to plot multiple cox proportional hazard models- both a univariate and multivariate model. Here is a working example using the provided dataset, 'df_surv'.

```
library(dcurves)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(survival)

# build Cox model
cox_model <- coxph(Surv(ttcancer, cancer) ~ famhistory + marker, data = df_surv);

# add model prediction to our data frame
df_surv_updated <- broom::augment( cox_model, newdata = df_surv %>% mutate(ttcancer = 1.5), type.predict = "expected" ) %>% mutate( pr_failure18 = 1 - exp(-.fitted) ) %>% select(-.fitted, -.se.fit);

# predict decision curve analysis
dca(Surv(ttcancer, cancer) ~ pr_failure18, 
    data = df_surv_updated,
    time = 1.5)
```

Using this code, although there are 2 different variables in the model, I am unable to compare the univariate and multivariate cox regression models. I would like to compare the univariate model only including 'marker' with the multivariate model including both 'famhistory' and 'marker'.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: How many questions are there? You can do an “analysis of deviance” to compare two Cox models. But seems you might also want something that you’re calling “decision curve analysis”, a term I am seeing for the first time here. Is this something that has a solid statistical basis and can you provide a good citation? Also. Read [MCVE] and [ask].

Comment: I now see that the dcurves vignette has that object and the exact code you are offering and creates both requested graphics. It’s unclear what is further needed.

Comment: The code listed will only create a curve for "treat all", "treat none" and the multivariate model. I would like a decision curve analysis plot that includes "treat all", "treat none", the univariate model, and also the multivariate model.